# Formatting data in firebase

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure the best way to structure my json. Essentially what I want to do is create multiple documents in my collection, let's say for clothes. One document would be shirts, then another for jeans, however each document has different brands, so within the shirts document, I created a brands array, then several other arrays for each size and the quantity left of each one. For simplicity, I have 4 arrays, one with the brand name, another with size small only containing quantity, another with medium, last one with large. Is there a way for me to just create one object in firebase with the brand name being a string, then small quantity being number, medium and large?

What I'm thinking about doing is creating a collection within the shirt for brands, then creating one document with three properties, small, med, large with quantity.

Comment: Cloud Firestore

Comment: Asking _"Is that really the best solution..."_ inherently invites opinion based answers, and that is off topic for SO. Can you remove that final sentence and ask a more focused question?

Comment: Oh cool thanks for the feedback, I just updated it, I just wanted to show I did some amount of research ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Essentially what I want to do is create multiple documents in my collection

This is what you should do.

> One document would be shirts, then another for jeans

No, you shouldn't create a document for each type of clothes, you should create a collection in which you should store cloth object as documents.

> I have 4 arrays, one with the brand name, another with size small only containing quantity, another with medium, last one with large.

No, this is not how you should make it.

> Is there a way for me to just create one object in firebase with the brand name being a string, then small quantity being number, medium and large?

Yes it is. Please see my structure below:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- shirts (collection)
   |    |
   |    --- shirtId (document)
   |          |
   |          --- brandName: "Nike"
   |          |
   |          --- sizes:
   |               |
   |               ---M: 10
   |               |
   |               ---L: 15
   |               |
   |               ---XL: 12
   |
   --- jeans (collection)
        |
        --- jeansId (document)
              |
              --- brandName: "Levi's"
              |
              --- sizes:
                   |
                   ---M: 10
                   |
                   ---L: 15
                   |
                   ---XL: 12
```

> What I'm thinking about doing is creating a collection within the shirt for brands, then creating one document with three properties, small, med, large with quantity. Is that really the best solution though?

Definitely not!

Comment: I like how shallow this structure is, however the quantity is specific to the size, so M might have a different quantity than L. How would I handle that?

Comment: Oh, I understand. I that case you should use a map, like in my updated answer.

Comment: Great, yes I think this works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

All right, so organize your data from general to particular, so we have:

```
-> Type of clothing
-> Brand
-> Model
-> Inventory
```

Therefore, you can have several root collections, and you can organize this however you want, and in fact, you can have duplicate trees, to support different queries. The concept of normalized data used on sql dbs doesn't really apply to nosql data stores, because they're hierarchical, it gets to a point where is easier and faster to have duplicates, than to traverse a very deep tree.

I'd put collections by type, then documents by brand, then an array of specific items with model-size-inventory:

```
/shirts
    *Hilfiger
        -Array {
                 Document: Model1 - Size XS - 1 Qty
                 Document: Model1 - Size XL - 0 Qty
               }
    *Levis
/pants
/jackets
```

Really, though, you have to look at your queries and try to model the data in a way that will support the most straightforward coding of the most common queries

Comment: Yeah, I come from a rdbms background and in that, it'd be simple to just create a row of data with the brand name, size, quantity, however I'm confused by your structure.

/shirts is a collection right?
Then Hilfiger is a document id, the document is an array? But what kind of array has a key value pair? Or is it another collection?

Comment: I'm thinking in order to minimize the shallowness, I might just add the type as a grouping in my document. How does that sound? So everything is in the outer document, then just has a "group" key and the value is shirts, pants, jackets?

Comment: Yes having the "type" as an a attribute is a good idea, because you can query for it in Firebase, using .where("type","==","shirt"), also, yes a document can have arrays of objects or subcollections. Actually to store it you don't even have to do it by pieces, just set a whole JSON object with sub-objects, and store the top, and done!